# Trying to make a custom print class where the application tells when to print a page

Tags: c#, printing

I'm building a series of apps for my place of business so I'm trying to create my own printing class that I can refer to for all of my applications.

The issue is, I'm trying to figure out a way for the application to tell the class when to print the page, and I am unable to find a way to do so.

For example, this is what I have so far:

```
    // Report Variables
    private bool bPrinting = false;
    private int iPage = 0;
    private float fOverflow = 0.00F;
    private string sPrintLine = null;
    private Font fontTmpFont = null;
    private PrintPageEventArgs ppeaEv = null;
    private Margins mMargins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(25, 25, 25, 25); // Set wide margins

    // Clear the print line
    public void LineClear()
    {
        sPrintLine = null;
    }

    // Insert a string into the print line at the specified position within the line
    public void LineInsert(string _InsertString, int _InsertPosition)
    {
        if (sPrintLine.Length <= _InsertPosition)
            sPrintLine = sPrintLine.PadLeft(_InsertPosition) + _InsertString;
        else if (sPrintLine.Length <= (_InsertPosition + _InsertString.Length))
            sPrintLine = sPrintLine.Substring(0, _InsertPosition) + _InsertString;
        else
            sPrintLine = sPrintLine.Substring(0, _InsertPosition) + _InsertString + sPrintLine.Substring(_InsertPosition + _InsertString.Length);
    }

    // Check to see if the line we're trying to print is at the end of the page
    public bool AtEndOfPage()
    {
        return AtEndOfPage(new Font("Courier", 10));
    }
    public bool AtEndOfPage(Font _Font)
    {
        if ((fOverflow + _Font.GetHeight(ppeaEv.Graphics)) > ppeaEv.MarginBounds.Height)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Attempt to print the line
    public void LinePrint()
    {
        LinePrint(null, null);
    }
    public void LinePrint(Font _Font)
    {
        LinePrint(_Font, null);
    }
    public void LinePrint(Font _Font, Brush _Color)
    {
        if (_Font == null)
            _Font = new Font("Courier", 10);
        if (_Color == null)
            _Color = Brushes.Black;

        ppeaEv.Graphics.DrawString(sPrintLine, _Font, _Color,
            ppeaEv.MarginBounds.Left, ppeaEv.MarginBounds.Top + fOverflow,
            new StringFormat()); // 'Draw' line on page
        fOverflow += _Font.GetHeight(ppeaEv.Graphics);
    }

    //  We are done with the report, tell the Print Service to finish up
    public void EndReport()
    {
        ppeaEv.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    //  This is what gets called when the user clicks on 'Print'
    private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = mMargins;   // Set margins for pages
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;    // Set Portrait mode
        printDocument.BeginPrint += new PrintEventHandler(printDocument_BeginPrint);
        printDocument.EndPrint += new PrintEventHandler(printDocument_EndPrint);

        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;                   // Set the Document for this print dialog
        printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;                      // Allow the user to select only some pages to print
        printDialog.ShowHelp = true;                            // Allow help button

        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print(); // Raises PrintPage event
        }

        printDocument.Dispose();
        printDialog.Dispose();
    }

    void printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        iPage = 0;
        fOverflow = 0.00F;

    }

    void printDocument_EndPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

As you may be able to tell, I'm trying to fill the page externally to the class, and then have the app tell the class when to print the page when "AtEndOfPage"

I know about "printDocument.PrintPage", but that doesn't seem to be what I need; It builds the page internal to the method and then prints it. I'm not going to be building the print page within that method.
 I also am trying to allow for multiple fonts on a single page.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you all in advance,
 Robert

Comment: I don't think you are right about the perceived limitations of using a `PrintPage` event. Like a `Paint` event it is meant to be the starting point for the printing but if you __pass on__ its parameters, esp. the `Graphics` object you can let any number of general purpose methods create the output. - The real challenge is to define a format in which all your apps can prepare and serve their data and their formatting including fonts, paragraph formatting and what not to the printing app. _ You may want to start by designing a class `PrintAction` which holds these things to be collected..

Comment: ..in a `List<PrintAction>` which gets processed from the PrintPage event..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you completely - :(  (I'm sorry - I'm trying)
Unless I am misunderstanding the PrintPage event (which is very possible), it gets raised when it's ready to have a page populated.  The 'printDocument_PrintPage' method then populates the page and then the page is printed.  I need the opposite; I need to tell the Print Events when a page is already populated (because that is done with the 'LinePrint' method) and then print it.

Comment: wait - you're saying that I should build the page first in a List<> (with the font, formatting ,etc.) and then once it's done, then call the Print class?
If that's it, then I am a little disappointed as I was hoping to have this class be able to be more 'direct' than that.

Comment: Yes, sort of. You  could prepare all data needed for printing in a list and then let the printpage work through such a list. That's what is done in screen drawing as well, albeit for a different reason: there the drawing must happen (repeately) whenever the screen needs updating. The parallel is that for both cases the actual graphics data must be stored somewhere where the paint/printpage methods can find and process them..

Comment: My usual DrawAction classes consist of a Type (Line, Rectanlge, Ellips, Text etc..) one or more Pens and Brushes, the Points, Text, Fonts and other data..  - good luck with the project!